# .NET Core 2.2 Dynamically load Connection Strings from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to load connection strings from the database and use it in a dbcontext?

Currently I have these set of tables in database A:

1. Company
2. User

One Company can have many Users

Company has a field called ConnectionString

My intention is that when a user belonging to a company logs in using database A, they find the dbcontext belonging to their company and then use it to load database B,C or whatever database their company uses.

I have tried searching for a solution for this but it doesn't seem to exist. Is it impossible?

EDIT:

This is how I load my dbContext in Startup.cs

```
 services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(SKCASGlobals.SK_ConnectionString));
```

This is how I then access my data from the database in a controller:

```
private readonly StarKeepDbContext dbContext;
private readonly ILogger<ProductData> logger;

public ProductData(StarKeepDbContext dbContext, ILogger<ProductData> logger)
{
    this.dbContext = dbContext;
    this.logger = logger;
}

public string Save(ProductDetailsViewModel Input)
{
    try
    {
        Product b = new Product
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Name = Input.Name,
            BrandId = Input.Brands.BrandId,
            CategoryId = Input.Categories.CategoryId,
            Unit = Input.Unit,
            Price = Input.Price,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
            UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now
        };
        dbContext.Product.Add(b);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return b.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of how to load a connection string from database A and use it here?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. Storing a connection string in a database field is a rather trivial thing to do.

Comment: Sorry, what I'm asking is how I can use that connection string. Storing it is not an issue.

Comment: Use one of these methods? [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsextensions?view=efcore-2.1), [Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlitedbcontextoptionsbuilderextensions.usesqlite?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but once you have a connection string you can pass it to the constructor of a `DbContext` or set the `Database.Connection.ConnectionString` property. Obviously you need to know the connection string required to connect to the database where the connection string you're after is defined.

Comment: But my dbcontext is set in Startup.cs? Thats where I'm stuck. I also edited the question with more details

Comment: You can inject your Company/User DbContext into your second context, then read the appropriate connection string from it and use in the `OnConfiguring` method to connect.

Comment: @Valuator thanks for replying. Do you have an example somewhere I can reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you simply meant to do?

[image]

Comment: @JianYA I think Nkosi answer is actually more appropriate for you are trying to do.

Comment: I understand his answer as well. However, in my structure, I will be accessing identically structured databases that may potentially be located in other servers, that means that I will need to use the Unit of Work method and this connection string to access the data from each database.

Comment: @JianYA well I am most curious about how you will use this approach for the different users since the user will be unknown at this point. You needed to use the user to find the company and connection string in the first database so you know how to connect to the second? correct? Or did I misunderstand your question

Comment: @Nkosi , for the individual user your method works. However, what happens when I have a user that has an administrator role? My administrator will need to have an overview of allp products located in the different databases and that means I will have to collect all connection strings and iterate through them and get the data at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Consider deferring the creation of the second context using the overload that gives access to the service provider.

For example

```
//...

services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(SKCASGlobals.SK_ConnectionString));

services.AddDbContext<StarKeepDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) => {
    var contextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var appData = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

    var userId = //...use the accessor to identify currently authenticated user

    //...and then extract the connection string from app data        
    var user = appData.Users.Where(u => user.SomeIdentifies == userId).FirstOrDefault();

    //Fail early
    if(user == null) throw new InvalidOperation("Invalid user");

    connectionString = user.Company.ConnectionString; //Assuming navigation property

    //set connection string
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
});

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

//...
```

The necessary information is extracted via the service provider and used to properly configure the context options.